# Do grammars with these properties have a name?

Tags: terminology, computational-linguistics

I'm interested in context-free grammars on a finite set of symbols where all the production rules replace a symbol by a string of length two. There is also one constraint: in the reductive direction the rules are deterministic. For example, $A\to BC$ and $D\to BC$ cannot both be in the set of rules.

In the reductive direction these grammars are like a general binary operation acting on a finite set, but where the operation may be undefined for some pairs of operands.

Whichever perspective (grammar or binary quasi-operation) is better known, I would like to know its name.

Comment: The "deterministic" reduction sound like having a "nondegenerate" (or "irredundant") finitely generated semigroup.  I don't know if there is a name for those semigroups with a presentation with relations going quadratic to linear.

Comment: I'd understand perfectly well, and the [EoM](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Binary_operation) endorses it, if you just called the opposite direction a partially defined binary operation.

Answer (score -1):

I fear you'll have to forge a name.

*Reversibly deterministic* seems appropriate for your rule, and I would shorten it into *reverministic*. Also, *exponential grammars* may be a way to describe the doubling length.

So, *reverministic exponential grammars* (*REG*) would be my proposal. Which, I acknowledge, is terrible.

Comment: I am reversely optimistic about your proposal :)